# Go httpClient memory leaks

Tags: http, go, memory-leaks

**UPDATED CODE**

Hi I have memory leaks in httpClient, i've added sync.WaitGroup and now I see that goroutine with httpClient don't closed. How to fix it?

```
func checkProxySOCKS(prox string, c chan QR, wg *sync.WaitGroup) (err error) {

defer wg.Done()
dialer, _ := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", prox, nil, proxy.Direct)

timeout := time.Duration(2 * time.Second)

httpClient := &http.Client{
    Timeout: timeout,
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        DisableKeepAlives: true,
        Dial:              dialer.Dial,
    },
}

res, err := httpClient.Get("https://telegram.org/")
if err != nil {

    c <- QR{Addr: prox, Res: false}
    return
}

defer res.Body.Close()
io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, res.Body)

c <- QR{Addr: prox, Res: true}

return nil
```

}
Here i create goroutines

```
for _, proxy := range splitedProxies {
    wg.Add(1)
    go checkProxySOCKS(proxy, respChan, &wg)
}

for range splitedProxies {
    wg.Add(1)
    r := <-respChan
    if r.Res {
        checkedProxiesArray = append(checkedProxiesArray, r.Addr)
    }
    wg.Done()
}

wg.Wait()
```

Comment: You're creating and discarding a new transport every time. That is going to leak connections.

Comment: Please refer https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/ : `Clients and Transports are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and for efficiency should only be created once and re-used.`

Comment: @Ravi but i'm need to insert new dialer to Transport all time

Comment: @ChunkCoder: I don't see why, but if you did need a dialer that makes a new proxy dialer every time, make yourself a type that does just that.

Comment: Not sure if this is the right way though, a counting semaphore for a pool of `http.Client` connections, would it help?

Comment: @JimB, keep-alive is disabled; this doesn't leak connections. ChunkCoder, use [pprof](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/) to figure out why the goroutines are blocking (probably on c <-).

Comment: @Peter, I'm check it, you are right (c <-) is problem, how to fix it? and why it happen?

Comment: Peter: sorry, that's correct in this case. @ChunkCoder, sending on a channel will block if there's no receiver. If you want this to be reliable you should probably also create a Dialer that can accept a cancellation context so the Dialer isn't able to block the goroutine as well.

Comment: I'm updated code and still have small leak

Comment: @ChunkCoder: if SOCKS5 returns an error you're not sending a corresponding value over respChan. There's no reason to use the `wg` in the second for loop. If there's still a leak, look at a stack trace and see what's blocking -- there's no timeout for the proxy dialer so that can still block.

Comment: Transport dies too slowly. I'v creating Transports for checking proxy every 2 minute, so new Transports creates faster that old dies.

Comment: @ChunkCoder, yes, you should be reusing the transport.

Comment: `Dial:              dialer.Dial,` is blocking transport, how to set timeout for it?

Comment: Use `DialContext` instead of the deprecated `Dial` field.

Comment: proxy package not support it, also I found this https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/net/+/37641

Comment: @ChunkCoder: I see. You could still use a Dialer in the Proxy with a default timeout, so it won't block indefinitely.

Comment: @JimB can you show example? cause I cant find how to add timeout to  Dialer

Comment: @ChunkCoder, rather than `proxy.Direct` (which just wraps the `net.Dial` function in a `Dialer` type), Use a `net.Dialer` with the `Timeout` field set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm read comments, so this should solve your problem

```
const (
    timeout = time.Duration(1000 * time.Millisecond)
    tt      = time.Duration(100 * time.Millisecond)
)

func checkProxySOCKS(prox string, c chan QR, wg *sync.WaitGroup) (err error) {

    defer wg.Done()

    d := net.Dialer{
        Timeout:   tt,
        KeepAlive: tt,
    }

    dialer, _ := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", prox, nil, &d)

    httpClient := &http.Client{
        Timeout: timeout,
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DisableKeepAlives: true,
            Dial:              dialer.Dial,
        },
    }

    res, err := httpClient.Get("https://telegram.org/")
    if err != nil {

        c <- QR{Addr: prox, Res: false}
        return
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()
    io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, res.Body)

    c <- QR{Addr: prox, Res: true}

    return nil
}
```